# How to scale a subplot dimensions of a 3d subplot to match 2d subplot with Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, mplot3d

I am trying to get the y-scale of both subplots to be at the same scale eg. subplot 1 (3d) not appearing smaller than subplot 2 (2d).  I have tried adding the `sharey` argument in the line `ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, )`.  I believe it is to do with subplot 1 not filling the given extent.

My working code example is:

```
from numpy import *
import mpl_toolkits.mplot3d.axes3d as p3
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig=plt.figure(figsize=(10,10), )
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 1, projection="3d", )

u=r_[0:2*pi:300j]
v=r_[0:2*pi:300j]

xi, yi, zi = 11.0, 11.0, 13.0
x=xi*outer(cos(u),sin(v))
y=yi*outer(sin(u),sin(v))
z=zi*outer(ones(size(u)),cos(v))
ax1.plot_surface(x,y,z, color="green", edgecolor="none", alpha=.5 )
ax1.view_init(elev=2., azim=40)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(1, 2, 2, )

pv = [14.05816239,38.8005282,59.04428205,74.78942393,86.03595384,92.78387179, \
      95.03317777,92.78387179,86.03595384,74.78942393,59.04428205,38.8005282, \
      14.05816239]

x = linspace(-13, 13, 13)

ax2.barh(x - 1, pv / sum(pv), 2, color="none", edgecolor="grey")
plt.show()
```

And the output looks like this:

[image]

Comment: More of a work around than a solution, but I have been using `gridspec` to rescale the second subplot to be approximate dimensions to the first.